# duplicate request by NSURLconnection

Tags: ios, cocoa, ios5, https

am using NSURLConnection to connect a server at the port 443 for authentication. Only for BAD credentials, its making two requests, even though i made only one request. I debugged by logging server & simulator/device using sniffer.

But i am making a  call only one time & getting only one response. i debugged it using NSLog in simulator/iphone/ipad

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. 
If you are using NSOperationQueue, set maxConcurrentOperationCount to 1. It will be fine.